# How to show a list of ParseUser that are in my list of contacts

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm working on an app and use Parse.com as my back-end service. I let user to signup or login to the app.
Is there a way to show to the currentUser (PargeUse.getCurrentUSer()) a list of a signed user that are also in its phone contact list?

I don't see any ParseQuery I need to use...

Maybe I need to compare the all the ParseUser in my app to the one that in my contact list but how?

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a field of phone number in Parse User table ,and at the time of signup user must enter its phone number to make signup.

By this way you will get the phone number of all signed user with the app (they will save in Parse user Table)

Now when you want to get a list of a signed user that are also in its phone contact list you can simply apply condition something like this:

```
 if(phonenum in you contact list.exists(TELEPHONE FIELD OF PARSE USER TABLE))
   {
    //here you get the list of signed users that are also in its phone contact list
   }
```